# How to change the language of a single document in Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-2016

My MS Office and Excel language is English. I am working with English documents most of the time, so I want to keep it that way. Temporarily changing the language options is also not an option.

When I am working with documents in other languages, this means that all the regional settings are overridden.

One example: In an English spreadsheet, the numbers are formatted as `1,234.56`. In most non-English languages, the comma (`,`) is used as the decimal separator, so the number should e.g. look like this: `1.234,56`.

If the spreadsheet is created by someone in a foreign language and I just want to open (maybe adjust) and print it, the format is broken.

How can I set the format of a single document in MS Excel (or Office)?

Comment: Have two accounts and have excel set differently. Or have a script that choses the excel settings file as excel opens based on your selection.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem! There has to be a way in office to set language of a file, can't believe that I have to switch language for entire office setup when working with different docs

Answer (score 1):

Excel seems a bit behind in that respect. My solution is to open the file in Google Sheets, where switching languages per document is very easy: File > Settings > Locale